# Clarification on std::cin

Tags: c++, stream

This is taken right from The "C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup. I would just like some clarification on how he accumulating the digits into the variable (int number_value). Please don't rip on the code, I didn't write it (Complete code from chapter 6 at bottom of post).

Specifically as the parser is calling the lexer, how is the lexer building up a number by using cin. I believe the answer is in these eight lines, but I would like an explanation of how it works.

```
if( isalpha( ch ) ) {
    (*input).putback( ch );
    (*input) >> string_value;
    return curr_tok=NAME;
} else {
    error( "bad token " );
    return curr_tok=PRINT;
}
```

It appears to me that the first time get_token( ) is called, it puts the full expression_list into cin or whatever input stream input points to (inside get_token( )).

```
(*input) >> ch;
```

I know ch is declared as a char, but what happens if you type 123.4+5.432; (assuming input is cin) cin now contains the "string" 123.4+5.432 contained in its stream. Then we move to the switch statement in the lexer (get_token( )). I am assuming: :

```
ch == 1?
```

at this point? Next inside the switch statement, we would "fall through" to the '.' case. Here we place '1' back into the stream and write it out to number_value?

```
(*input).putback( ch );
(*input) >> number_value;
```

Now number_value = 1, and we return to the parser. Since we found a NUMBER it calls get_token( ) again. And cin operator<< is called again. Wouldn't the next call to (*input)>> number_value place 2 into number value overwriting the 1 (assuming that the input is still 123.4+5.432)? What happens here. I guess I need a better understanding of how streams work. If someone could take the time, and give a brief explanation and point me to a good resource I would greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Matthew Hoggan

For those that don't have the book, the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <cctype>

std::istream *input;

double number_value;
int no_of_errors;
std::string string_value; 
std::map<std::string,double> table;

enum Token_value {
    NAME,        NUMBER,        END,
    PLUS='+',    MINUS='-',     MUL='*',       DIV='/',  
    PRINT=';',   ASSIGN='=',    LP='(',        RP=')'
}; 

Token_value curr_tok=PRINT;

double expr( bool );
double term( bool );
double prim( bool );
Token_value get_token( );
double error( std::string s ) {
    no_of_errors++;
    std::cerr << "error: " << s << std::endl;
    return 1.0;
}

Token_value get_token( ) {
    char ch = 0;
    (*input) >> ch;

    switch( ch ) {
        case 0: {
            return curr_tok=END;
        }
        case ';': 
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '(':
        case ')':
        case '=': {
            return curr_tok = static_cast<Token_value>( ch );
        }
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
        case '.': {
            (*input).putback( ch );
            (*input) >> number_value;
            return curr_tok=NUMBER;
        }
        default: {
            if( isalpha( ch ) ) {
                (*input).putback( ch );
                (*input) >> string_value;
                return curr_tok=NAME;
            } else {
                error( "bad token " );
                return curr_tok=PRINT;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) {
    switch( argc ) {
        case 1: {
            input = &std::cin;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            input = new std::istringstream( argv[1] );
            break;
        }
        default: {
            error(" To many arguments" );
            return 1;
        }
    }
    table["pi"] = 3.1415926535897932385;
    table["e"] = 2.7182818284590452354;

    while( (*input) ) {
        get_token( );
        if( curr_tok == END ) {
            break;
        }
        if( curr_tok == PRINT ) {
            continue;
        }
        std::cout << expr( false ) << std::endl;
    }

    if( input != &std::cin ) {
        delete input;
    }

    return 0;
}

double expr( bool get ) {
    double left = term( get );

    for( ; ; ) {
        switch( curr_tok ) {
            case PLUS: {
                left += term( true );
                break;
            }
            case MINUS: {
                left -= term( true );
                break;
            }
            default: {
                return left;
            }
        }
    }
}

double term( bool get ) { 
    double left = prim( get );
    for( ; ; ) {
        switch( curr_tok ) {
            case MUL: {
                left *= prim( true );
                break;
            }
            case DIV: {
                if( double d = prim( true ) ) {
                    left /= d;
                    break;                   
                }
                else {
                    return error( "divide by 0" );
                }
            }
            default: {
                return left;
            }
        }
    }
}

double prim( bool get ) {
    if( get ) {
        get_token( );
    }

    switch( curr_tok ) {
        case NUMBER: {
            double v = number_value;
            get_token( );
            return v;
        }
        case NAME: {
             double &v = table[string_value];
             if( get_token( ) == ASSIGN ) {
                 v = expr( true );
                 return v;
             }
        }
        case MINUS: {
            return -prim( true );
        }
        case LP: {
            double e = expr( true );
            if( curr_tok != RP ) {
                return error( "')' expected" );
            }
            get_token( );
            return e;
        }
        default: {
            return error( "primary expected" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'trick' is caused by the differing behaviour of the following three lines:

```
char ch;                   std::cin >> ch;
std::string string_value;  std::cin >> string_value;
double number_value;       std::cin >> number_value;
```

The first just gets a single character, the second and third get *multiple* characters to build a variable of the correct type.

Strings overload the global `operator>>` function to provide a version for strings, and this version uses whitespace as the delimiter (if you need to input spaces with your string, you should look into `getline`).

The double version uses the `istream& operator>> (double& val);` member function and will read characters only while they make sense in forming a double value.

So, let's say you enter `abc`. The code `cin >> ch` will populate `ch` with the character `'a'`, removing it from the input stream. You will then detect this with `isapha` in the default case since it matches none of the other cases.

At that point, you push that character `'a'` back on to the input stream so you can re-read it, and execute `cin >> string_value` which gets the entire string `abc`, *not* a single character.

Similarly, if you entered `3.14159`, it would be caught by the `case '3'` check, the character would be pushed back on to the input stream, and `cin >> number_value` would then get the whole value.

Answer (score 2):

> Now number_value = 1, and we return to the parser.

No. `(*input) >> number_value;` reads-in the whole double, i.e., 123.4 since number_value is of type double. Other than this, you are right.

Comment: SO it reads until it finds white space? I remember reading that >> reads until it finds white space where as while( cin.get( ch ) && !isalpha( ch ) ) { ;} would read untill it finds the first non digit?

Comment: @Matthew; No. The stream operators will reads upto the first character that does not fit the type being read.